# Where to get world-wide detailed administrative boundaries?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, administrative-boundaries

I'm looking to build a world map that plots all application users and their locations around the world. The initial zoomed out world view would show total numbers clustered by country, then when you click on these numbers it would zoom to that country and show a further clustering based on state/county within that country.

Where can I find data to produce these sort of visualizations? US State geojson data seems readily available but what about the rest of the world? What is the generic term for this level of zoom (states in US, counties in UK for example) to aid my search?

Comment: You might be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34648773/framework-for-plotting-latitude-longitude-in-a-map-based-on-country-state-and-d/34650249#34650249

Comment: Have you looked at [Natural Earth](http://NaturalEarthData.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find data to produce these sort of visualizations?

You're asking for administrative boundaries. How to get the official version depends on the country's administration. As far as I'm aware, a normalized dataset for all official administrative boundaries doesn't exist. IMHO the closest you might get to that is Natural Earth or OpenStreetMap.

This is not an easy task. I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166419/how-to-download-the-county-boundaries-of-china-in-openstreetmap, https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/, http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/, https://mapzen.com/blog/who-s-on-first/, and https://mapzen.com/data/borders/ *for a start*.

> What is the generic term for this level of zoom (states in US, counties in UK for example) to aid my search?

Once again, there is no normalized way of doing so, as each country uses a different naming scheme. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level

---

Also, be aware that you're using the (wrong) assumption that any given user in any given point will belong to one *and just one* administrative area (at any given "level"). This is not the case, specially for [contested territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes). Do **not** expect administrative boundaries to perfectly fit against each other.

Comment: Very useful thank you, Admin 0 might be what I'm looking for if I was to provide a "max zoom" level of boundary marking (state/county level)